Baking an armature with all of its attached mesh accessories....successfuly?
Blender 4./ Rigify
I have been kicked out of Bing coz it cant resolve this issue. (it got tired of the conversation)
Baking an animated character for .gtLF. Follow instructions to the letter....hundreds of times in various ways. Everything bakes and looks good but Im left with armature modifiers on the shoes etc (Geometry) Even though I opt to remove parents, constraints and bake to visual keying etc.
At some point I have checked every check box and shift select both pose and object. Nothing, nothing at all will make the armature modifier on the mesh of the shoe(s) go away. This is an issue for the .glTF engine as it can only reliably handle 1 armature and mesh. Im not able to share the file unfortunatley but can offer screen shots if required.
My process is as follows:
Select Geometry then lastly the armature. Enter Pose Mode. with all items selected go to Pose > Animation > Bake Action. Fill out the resulting dialogue box as required and presto  done........except not really coz the clothes didnt bake (Meshes attached to the rig)... They look like they baked but when I go to the geometry to check to see the armature modifier is gone, it is still attached and active.
What am I missing?
